# console.log string inside array object with angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-scope

I want to console.log or target the string of an object inside array with angularjs but it doesn't work. Please help me I'm still new on angularjs.

Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Profile Details AngularJS 1.X</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
           <div class="container" ng-app="DetailApp">
           <div ng-controller="PostController">   
</div>
</div>

<script>

  var app = angular.module('DetailApp', []);
  app.controller('PostController', function($scope) {
                  
    $scope.details = [{firstname: "Dave", lastname: "Del Rio"}, {firstname: "Gerald", lastname: "Kingston"}, {firstname: "Larry", lastname: "Jackson"}];
    
    if ($scope.details.firstname == "Dave Del Rio") {
      console.log("Hello Dave!")
    }  
    else {
      console.log("sorry, You're not welcome!")
    };  
                  
  });
  
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to target the firstname "Dave" inside the array object but It doesn't work at all.

Comment: Are you trying to check every element in the array or just the first element?

Comment: yes I just I want to check every element in the array

Comment: i jus want to check if the element inside the object and array is correct.

Comment: Perhaps you want `if ($scope.details.some(x => x.firstname === 'Dave' && x.lastname === 'Del Rio'))`

Comment: also want to target the string inside the array object

Comment: sorry but it does't work :(

Comment: sorry it works now! i accidentally add }; before else statement but it work perfectly now, Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any element in an array matches a condition.

```js
if ($scope.details.some(x => x.firstname === 'Dave' && x.lastname === 'Del Rio'))
```

Comment: thanks well explained! sorry for my english I'm asian and I can't clearly explain my problem but you still give what I want :)